# Question about the exercise 2.5.50 of Folland's textbook

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Suppose $(X, \mathcal{M}, \mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space and $f \in L^{+}(X)$ where $f: X\to [0,\infty]$ are all measurable functions. Let 
>   $$G_f = \{ (x,y) \in X \times [0, \infty]: y \le f(x) \}.$$
>
> > The book gives the hint that the map $(x,y) \to f(x)-y$ is the composition of $(x,y) \to (f(x),y)$ and $(z,y) \to z -y$.

(1)My question is how to prove the map $h: (x,y)\to (f(x),y)$ is measurable by the coordinate function is measurable?

(2)And why $(z,y)=z-y$ is measurable by the continuous function?

(3)Also, what does the "$\sigma$-finite " work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Theorem (2.2)**: If $X$ and $Y$ are measurable topological spaces and $f : X \to Y$ is continuous, the $f$ is measurable. Here $s := (z,y) \mapsto z - y : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is continuous.

The map $p:= (x,y) \mapsto (f(x), y) : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is the tensor product of the measurable maps $f = x \mapsto f(x) : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathrm{id} = x \mapsto x : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and therefore measurable. (**Proposition (2.4)**)

A composition of measurable functions is measurable. (Text at beginning of **section 2.1**). Thus $h = s \circ p : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable.

I'm not sure, but the $\sigma$-finiteness is probably needed to prove the $\mu \times m(G_f) = \int f \, d\mu$ part of the exercise, since it's a premise of **(2.37) The Fubini-Tonelli Theorem**.

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!