# Question about hint from Folland's exercise 2.5.50

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

This question is related to the exercise that was mentioned [in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3391437/question-about-the-exercise-2-5-50-of-follands-textbook), and is primarily about the hint provided to prove $G_{f} = \{(x,y)\in X\times[0,\infty]:y\leq f(x)\}$ is measurable. The solutions I have seen follow the hint, but I am wondering if it is possible to note that since $h(y) = -y$ is Borel measurable, and since it is known that $f\in L^{+}$, can we instead just use the fact that function measurability is closed under addition to show $G_{f}$ is measurable, or is this not correct in this instance? In other words, can we use
$$f\in L^{+}, \hspace{1mm} h\in \mathcal{B}\implies g(x,y) = f(x) + h(y) = f(x) + (-y) = f(x) - y$$
to show that $G_{f}$ is measurable, or does this not actually show that $g$ is measurable? I understand what to do with the hint provided by Folland, but I am not sure if it is acceptable to alternatively use the previously mentioned approach as shown above.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. You have to be careful with $\infty - \infty$, but defining $\infty - \infty$ you can show that sums of extended real valued measurable functions are measurable. There are related exercises about this measurability of extended real valued functions in Folland's book.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, it is helpful.